# How to enable the SSLv3 setting in ibm java 8

Tags: java, aix, ibm-jdk

I use `IBM JDK J9` on `AIX` OS.

I want to know what I need to change in the `java.security` file to enable the `SSLv3` Secure Socket Layer protocol. Or is there another file that needs to be changed to enable this protocol?

Comment: You really want to enable a protocol that is deprecated because it is inherently [**unsafe**](http://disablessl3.com/) and so should never ever be used again???

Answer (score 2):

Delete or comment out the following line "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3"